Image alignment issues in Tailwindcss
I'm trying to create a website and using tailwindcss for the frontend part of it. (I'm using stock images in this post)

And as you can see above, i can not align the two images, (the third image gets pushed down because the 2nd one is in its spot) it is perfectly fine before i add incline-block in order to have the Text over the images in the right position.
here is the code to this section:
      <div class="relative ml-14 mt-2 inline-block">
        <img src="stockimage" alt="" class="float-left transition transform rounded-lg">
        <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 px-8 py-4 transition transform">
          <h1 class="text-white font-bold text-xl transition-transform transform hover:scale-105">Something</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="relative mr-14 mt-2 inline-block">
        <img src="stockimage" alt="" class="float-right transition transform rounded-lg">
        <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 px-8 py-4 transition transform">
          <h1 class="text-white font-bold text-xl transition-transform transform hover:scale-105">Something</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="relative mr-14 mt-2 inline-block">
        <img src="stockimage" alt="" class="float-right transition transform rounded-lg">
        <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 px-8 py-4 transition transform">
          <h1 class="text-white font-bold text-xl transition-transform transform hover:scale-105">Something</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

I have tried some alternative methods but I couldn't get any result out of them, Any help would be much appreciated.
I used grid css as it was suggested however it is not irregular.


Have you thought about using Css grid?

Im not really knowledgeable on that. Can you provide a source about Irregular css grid that you think is good?

There's an interesting blog post from FreeCodeCamp that you can read, styles are written in pure css, but anything that's written there can be written in tailwind aswell, you can read it in the docs starting from grid template columns to grid auto rows.

I did attempt it using various different sources, but it does not help in this situation (with my skills)

Ok so you need a solution instead of sources? i can provide one

Any help is great thanks :)

Tailwind playground
Using css flexbox:
<div class="ml-14 mr-14 mt-2 flex flex-row gap-4">
  <div class="relative inline-block">
    <img src="https://c7.alamy.com/compfr/pyeg09/jeune-femme-prend-des-photos-sur-une-rue-de-la-ville-pyeg09.jpg" alt="" class="float-left transform rounded-lg transition" />
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 transform px-8 py-4 transition">
      <h1 class="transform text-xl font-bold text-white transition-transform hover:scale-105">Something</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col gap-4">
    <div class="relative inline-block flex-1">
      <img src="https://qodeinteractive.com/magazine/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Featured-Stock.jpg" alt="" class="float-right h-full w-full transform rounded-lg object-cover transition" />
      <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 transform px-8 py-4 transition">
        <h1 class="transform text-xl font-bold text-white transition-transform hover:scale-105">Something</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="relative inline-block flex-1">
      <img src="https://qodeinteractive.com/magazine/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Featured-Stock.jpg" alt="" class="float-right h-full w-full transform rounded-lg object-cover transition" />
      <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 transform px-8 py-4 transition">
        <h1 class="transform text-xl font-bold text-white transition-transform hover:scale-105">Something</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


I did achieve a similar result, however its not irregular which is what im aiming for and i will edit the post to show what using grid looks like. Thanks for the help!

ok so you need the right images to be wider?

yup, and the left one to be narrower

Great, then i'll edit the post to provide the correct solution

i've just updated the post, last one should work

Yup its perfect now! thanks! Im now gonna learn gridcss
